# react-meta-tags: keeps adding meta tags

Tags: html, reactjs, http-headers

So i'm using react-meta-tags to put some facebook open graph tags into the head depending on the page the user is looking at, so that shares work correctly. however when using react-meta-tags todo this, it just keeps adding the tags to the head and not deleting the old ones as you navigate around the site. it means the head fills up with loads of meta tags! :D

```
import React from "react";    
import MetaTags from 'react-meta-tags';

const Meta = () => {
  return (
    <div>
    <MetaTags>
      <title>Site Title</title>
      <meta property="og:url" content="http://www.example.com" />
      <meta property="og:type" content="music.playlist" />
      <meta property="og:title" content="Site Title" />
      <meta property="og:description" content="Description" />
      <meta property="og:image" content="url to image" />
    </MetaTags>      
    </div>
  )
}
export default Meta;
```

in the documentation it says this:

**Note : Define id on tags so if you navigate to other page, older meta tags will be removed and replaced by new ones.**

However they give no example of this on their github page:
https://github.com/s-yadav/react-meta-tags i when i ad "id=" to any of the tags it still doesnt work :(

Comment: also, when the built files are deployed the meta tags are not present at all, however they are when the file is served locally :(

Comment: use react-helmet for this, [link](https://github.com/nfl/react-helmet)

Comment: i've used react helmet and react meta tags and they both dont work when trying to use facebook open graph tags. they render the tags but facebook doesnt pick them up, i guess cause its a SPA and not rendered by the server ?

Comment: Same issue with react-helmet, in my case I see the `theme-color` meta tag being added twice